# Operator precedence and struct definition in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, casting

```
struct struct0 {
  int a;
};

struct struct1 {
  struct struct0 structure0;
  int b;
} rho;


&rho->structure0; /* Reference 1 */
(struct struct0 *)rho; /* Reference 2 */
(struct struct0)rho; /* Reference 3 */
```

1. From reference 1, does the compiler take the address of rho, and then access structure0, or vice-versa?
2. What does the line at reference 2 do?
3. Since structure0 is the first member of struct1, would reference 3 be equivalent to reference 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order of your references:

1. the `->` has higher precedence than the `&`.  You're going to get the address of `rho->structure0`.  Or rather, you would if `rho` were a pointer.  Since it's not, you'll get a compile error.
2. That won't work - you're casting a structure to a pointer type - you should get compiler error doing that.
3. You can't do that either.  A typecast to a non-scalar type is also an error.

Your examples #2 and #3 are covered by the standard section 6.5.4:

> Unless the type name specifies a void type, the type name shall specify qualified or
>   unqualified scalar type and the operand shall have scalar type.

If you put any of that code in a compiler you'd see the same results; is the code you're showing not what you intended to ask about?

Comment: If the first member of rho was a pointer, would references 1 and 2 be equivalent?

Comment: @Yktula, no, they still wouldn't work.  `rho` itself needs to be a pointer to try any of that stuff.

Comment: You're right. struct s1 { struct { int n } *s0; } *s1; main() { (&s1->sch == (struct s0 *)s1) ? printf("Yes") : exit(EXIT_FAILURE); return 0; } prints Yes. Thank you.

Comment: @CarlNorum what is the difference in operations between a.b->c and a->b.c? Is it (a.b)->c and (a->b).c respectively?

Comment: @Turbo, yes both of those look right. They don't mean the same thing though - you can't do both of those given the same `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 2):

```
&rho->structure0; /* Reference 1 */
(struct struct0)rho; /* Reference 3 */
(struct struct0 *)rho; /* Reference 2 */
```

All the three reference is not right:

- rho is not a pointer. So you can not
  do `rho->structure0` but
  `(&rho)->structure0`
- You can not convert a variable to a
  pointer, so you can not do `(struct
  struct0)rho;` but `(struct struct0
  *)&rho`

I quite dont really understand what you want to do, so I can not help you much.